# How are new antigens recognised by the body?

Tags: immunology

I understand that non-self cells are engulfed by APCs, and are recognised by Helper T cells for the cell-mediated response to occur, but the Helper T cell must have the specific binding for such an interaction to occur surely? How are such new binding sites available in naive Helper T cells for the recognition of the antigen to occur?

Answer (score -1):

Helper T cell (CD4+) with it's T cell receptors (TCRs) can only recognize an antigen when it is complexed with major histocompatibility complex (MHC class II) molecules on the surface of other cells. T cell receptor binds to the MHC-antigen complex.

This guy explains it very well https://youtu.be/TadJkUCJLHo

references:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/neuroscience/mhc-class-ii